# recovering a redis data which was flushed using "FLUSHALL"

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I accidentally flushed all data from redis using

```
`FLUSHALL`
```

is there a way to recover the data

Comment: Is this ElastiCache you are talking about? You have tagged this with AWS but provided no details in your question. If ElastiCache, have you taken any recent snapshots?

Comment: yes it is an elastic cache. No i haven't taken any snapshot

Comment: I think you're out of luck if you never took any backups and you didn't have automatic backups configured.

Comment: ya i think that too.